# Finding width of hidden element similar to jQuery in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replicate the jQuery width function using pure JavaScript. Pure JavaScript functions such as getComputedStyle or offsetWidth seem to work if the element is visible, but I cannot replicate the same behavior when the element is hidden.

It seems that jQuery is doing something different here and I cannot figure out what exactly.

To clearly explain what i am trying to do, Here is a codepen example where I try the getComputedStyle in comparison with the jQuery width function for calculating the width of a hidden element that is changing dynamically.

```js
const input = $('input');
const sizer = $('.sizer');
const sizerDom = document.querySelector('.sizer');


input.on('input', evt => {
  sizer.text(evt.target.value);
  console.log(sizer.width())
  console.log(getComputedStyle(sizerDom, null).width);
});
```

```css
.sizer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span class="sizer">
```

https://codepen.io/OmranAbazid/pen/OJNXyoG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in jQuery's internal logic, [it interally swaps the `display` property from `none` to another value](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L307) so that it forces the browser to momentarily render it. Otherwise the measurements will always be `0` since the element is never rendered.

Also, instead of trying to use `window.getComputedStyle` which will return a string value of the CSS dimension (e.g. `100px`), you can use `sizerDom.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the actual number instead (which returns, say, `100`) without needing to do additional parsing.

```js
const input = $('input');
const sizer = $('.sizer');
const sizerDom = document.querySelector('.sizer');


input.on('input', evt => {
  sizer.text(evt.target.value);
  console.log(sizer.width())
  
  const cachedDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(sizerDom).display;
  sizerDom.style.display = 'inline-block';
  console.log(sizerDom.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  sizerDom.style.display = cachedDisplay;
});
```

```css
.sizer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span class="sizer">
```

Comment: OP wanted to get the width of `hidden` element in JS - You are doing this by some kind hack to use `inline-block` - Which is NOT very ideal or a wanted solution according to the title of this question- `getBoundingClientRect()` does not work on `hidden` elements.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I'm not really sure what your gripe is about: OP is asking how jQuery does it, and I simply showed him the "hack" that jQuery uses to sniff out dimensions of a visibly hidden element. Not living up to your username much?

Comment: Please do not take my comments personal. I like the hack you did honestly. I never thought of that. As per OP question i assumed that he wanted specifically for hidden `el` in pure JS without the `hack` Great answer i appreciate that!